# Ricoh Aficio MP C2030 RPCS Driver for Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 Bit)

Tags: windows, drivers, 64-bit, printer, windows-server-2012

Where can I find Ricoh Aficio MP C2030 RPCS Driver for Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 Bit)? I checked the following link:
http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/ra/model/mpc20l/mpc20len.htm#Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)

Earlier, while I was using Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 Bit), I downloaded the RPCS driver from the given link. Now I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit), but I can't find the RPCS driver from the website. Now I installed 'Driver for XPS' as my printer driver.This is not the appropriate driver because it is taking more time for monochrome prints and even more time for colour prints than the RPCS driver in 2008 Server.

Can anyone help me to find the RPCS driver? If the RPCS driver is not not available for Windows 2012 server, which is the best suitable driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ricoh stopped supplying an RPCS driver after Windows 7/Server 2008. Use one of the drivers available at this link:

http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/ra/model/mpc20l/mpc20len.htm#Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)

The RPCS driver treats the printer like a GDI printer. GDI printers have very little intelligence and rely on the Windows graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper. Your printer has support for languages like PCL and PostScript, which do this conversion inside the printer, thus putting less load on the PC's processor.

PostScript is the best language to use if you are heavily into graphics. For ordinary documents, PCL5 or PCL6 usually are the best. All of these are available from the above link.

Comment: With PCL 5 & 6 I cannot print anything.

Comment: What happens when you try? Any error messages anywhere? Have you tried PostScript?

Comment: With PCL 5 or 6 driver installed, I cannot print. When print command is given nothing happens. And, I am not experienced with PostScript.

Comment: You might be out of luck. Specs for your printer say that PCL is "optional". So, unless you have that option installed, only the RPCS driver will do. Unless the Server 2008 driver works, you may need to install that option - if you can still find it. And, as the printer is quite old, that may be a problem.

Comment: Now printing is very slow. Is there any other way to speed up the printing? Can I try installing RPCS driver for 2008 Server?

Comment: Yes, you can. But what driver is printing very slow???

Comment: Driver for XPS is slow.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error on the MP C2030 when you try to print? Does the print job leave the queue?  Nothing happening at all is very unusual.